# ASP.NET ajax call using Jquery adds to list

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a simple UI where I am trying to populate the select dropdown using data from database. I am doing this by a AJAX call to fetch the data.

The C# web method looks like

```
private static List<List<string>> componentTypeDropDown = new List<List<String>>();

private void loadDropDownList()
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT FieldName,FieldLabel FROM dropDownFields", conn);
    conn.Open();
    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
       List<String> temp = new List<string>();
       temp.Add((string)dr.GetValue(0));
       temp.Add((string)dr.GetValue(1));
       componentTypeDropDown.Add(temp);
       conn.Close();
    }
}

[WebMethod]
public static ArrayList getComponentType()
{
    ArrayList compType = new ArrayList();
    for (int i=0;i<componentTypeDropDown.Count();i++)
    {
       compType.Add(new { label = componentTypeDropDown[i][0], value = componentTypeDropDown[i][1] });
    }
    return compType;
}
```

The AJAX call looks like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "salesQuote.aspx/getComponentType",
    data: "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
          console.log("karan");
    },
    error: function () {                   
          alert("Failed to load names");
    }
});
```

Every time I refresh or even restart the server the value of msg in success callback has previous values as well. For example lets say my database has value 1,2. First time I call ajax msg is 1,2 if i refresh the value is 1,2,1,2 and so on. Even if I close the server and start again the value would be 1,2,1,2,1,2

Comment: where do you call method `loadDropDownList`

Comment: I suspect somehow this method is being called multiple times. Can't be sure though without knowing the actual code setup. You can try counting the no. of calls to method `loadDropDownList` by keeping a breakpoint.

Comment: you are right everytime the page loads its calling that method and hence values gets added again.

Comment: Try tu use  compType.Clear(); before you create your arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Your ComponentTypeDropdown is a static, so every time you call 'LoadDropdownList' this list will add new items, whitout removing the old ones.

I would suggest that you add following line in the loadDropDownList method:

```
 private void loadDropDownList()
    {
        componentTypeDropdown.RemoveAll();
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT FieldName,FieldLabel FROM dropDownFields", conn);
        conn.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
           List<String> temp = new List<string>();
           temp.Add((string)dr.GetValue(0));
           temp.Add((string)dr.GetValue(1));
           componentTypeDropDown.Add(temp);
           conn.Close();
        }
    }
```